# How to increase the speed of a report consist of ISNULL() function in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a report that is slow , I found out which part of query is slow , it's related to a `WHERE` clause of an `INSERT`. In this `WHERE` clause there are some `ISNULL()` functions which make the report slow .

These tables are used by `left join` : `CshTransBys` & `CshTransOwners`. Some fields of these tables are :

- **`CshTransBys`**'s columns: (`PPCode`, `PBCode`, `PCCode`, `GPCode`, `GBCode` , `GCCode`, ...).
- **`CshTransOwners`**'s columns : (`PPCodeTOS` , `PBCodeTOS`, `PCCodeTOS` , `GPCodeTOS`, `GBCodeTOS` , `GCCodeTOS` , ...).

And finally the code related to `ISNULL()` function in the `where` clause are :

```
   ) or
   ((@Ptype in (11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25)) and (isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode)<>0)) or
   ((@Ptype in (12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25)) and (isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode)<>0)) or
   ((@Ptype in (14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 24, 25)) and (isnull(PCCodeTOS,PCCode)<>0)) or

   ((@PType=0)and (isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode) = @PCode)) or
   ((@PType=1)and (isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode) = @PCode)) or
   ((@PType=2)and (isnull(PCCodeTOS,PCCode) = @PCode)) 

)
```

My question is that how can I handle this problem, I mean how can I get rid of those `isnull()`, by replacing some thing else?, using them some where else ?

Comment: As per me,not "Isnull()" but "or" in where clause is affecting your performance.

Comment: When I omit just those IsNull() parts, the speed increase

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to a concept called SARGability. In essence, because you're running a column through a scalar function, the optimizer has no way to know what the output will be. In your case though, the fix is easy enough; be explicit about how you want to treat null values. That is

```
Isnull(a, b) =0
```

Turns into

```
(a=0 or (a is null and b=0))
```

Comment: Wonder why the query optimizer does not do that?

Comment: It sure would be nice, eh? Especially for this specific case; it's not as though rewrite rules don't exist elsewhere…

Answer (score 0):

The reason is rather simple: It is very easy for the dbms to find the records in CshTransOwners where PPCodeTOS equals @PCode - it can use an index. But to get those records where the PPCodeTOS equals @PCode plus those where PPCodeTOS is null, but PPCode in CshTransBys equals @PCode is quite another.

To elaborate: This is quick: Find records in one table with an index, then get the matching records of another table. This is slow: join two tables, then filter the result records by first looking at a column of the first table and in case of null there looking at a column of the other table.

You cannot do anything about this. It's just the way it works.

You can replace `isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode) = @PCode` of course with `PPCodeTOS = @PCode OR (PPCodeTOS IS NULL AND PPCode = @PCode)`, but this shouldn't change anything, because this is about the same that isnull does. Well, you can try.

You can also add superfluous criteria and hope this to help the dbms:

```
(PPCodeTOS = @PCode OR PPCode = @PCode) AND isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode) = @PCode
```

But it's not likely either to have any effect. With so many ORs the dbms is not likely to use an index here.

Comment: the reason is not the index. Well it can't use any existing indexes. But the real problem is that it has to make several calculations on all rows. So that is what makes it slow also when no index exists.

Comment: That's correct , accually first of all I checked if it needed any indexes, since it was requered one I added it to CshTransBys Table. The report execution took 4 min before now it takes 2 min. . These parts caused the query be still slow :

(isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode)<>0))
(isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode)<>0)) 
(isnull(PCCodeTOS,PCCode)<>0))

Answer (score 0):

I think you can definitely trim it down

```
   or
   (
        (@Ptype in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)) 
        and (PBCodeTOS<>0 or (PBCodeTOS is null and PBCode<>0))
        -- and (isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode)<>0)
   ) 
   or 
   (
        (@PType in (0,1,2))
        and (PBCodeTOS<>0 or (PBCodeTOS is null and PBCode<>0))
        -- and (isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode)<>0)
   )
```

your query

```
   (
        (@Ptype in (11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25)) 
        and (isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode)<>0)
   ) 
   or
   (
        (@Ptype in (12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25)) 
        and (isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode)<>0)
   ) 
   or
   (
        (@Ptype in (14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 24, 25)) 
        and (isnull(PCCodeTOS,PCCode)<>0)
   ) 
   or
   (
       (@PType=0)
       and (isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode) = @PCode)
   ) 
   or
   (
       (@PType=1) 
       and (isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode) = @PCode)
   ) 
   or
   (
       (@PType=2) 
       and (isnull(PCCodeTOS,PCCode) = @PCode)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL` is not [SARGEABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). SQL Server doesn't know which rows satisfy the condition of `isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode)<>0`, so it must apply `ISNULL` to all rows then filter out the result set. Indexes are useless in this case.

Replace `ISNULL` with explicit checks for NULLs:

```
or
   (@Ptype in (11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25) and ((PPCodeTOS IS NOT NULL and PPCodeTOS <> 0) or (PPCodeTOS IS NULL and PPCode <> 0))) or
   (@Ptype in (12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25) and ((PBCodeTOS IS NOT NULL and PBCodeTOS <> 0) or (PBCodeTOS IS NULL and PBCode <> 0))) or
   (etc.)
```

It looks much more verbose, but if speed is youer #1 concern, this may help.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the answers, accually first of all I checked if it needed any indexes, since it was requered one I added it to CshTransBys Table. The report execution took 4 min before now it takes 2 min. .
These parts caused the query be still slow :

```
(isnull(PPCodeTOS,PPCode)<>0))
(isnull(PBCodeTOS,PBCode)<>0)) 
(isnull(PCCodeTOS,PCCode)<>0))
```